# Stop 'Connection refused' errors in production

Tags: http, https, sockets, heroku, cdn

I recently began receiving `error: [Errno 111] Connection refused` errors from `http://yandex.com/bots` that crawl my website in production. I do not mind that they are crawling the site, but would rather not receive these emails.

My hunch is that they are being denied because they are using `http` and port `80` while my website requires `https`. In this case, it is good that they are being denied. However, I am not sure why I am getting these errors (4-5 times per day since last week).

Any thoughts on how to stop these errors? I am using Python 2.7, Heroku, and Cloudflare.

```
Internal Server Error: /team/46/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/wehealth/wehealth/utils.py", line 121, in __render_with
    d = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/wehealth/users/views.py", line 737, in team
    team = get_group(team, team_id, team_key)
  File "/app/wehealth/wehealth/utils.py", line 770, in get_group
    group = get_group_goals(group)
  File "/app/wehealth/wehealth/utils.py", line 786, in get_group_goals
    createGoal2Group.delay(group['info'], g)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 453, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 354, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 470, in _ensured
    interval_max)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 382, in ensure_connection
    interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 246, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 250, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 756, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 711, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Request repr(): 
<WSGIRequest
path:/team/46/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'y8sR9HccmrzW8RaYDQwmalvKiRl2E6DK',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_CONNECT_TIME': '0',
 'HTTP_FROM': 'support@search.yandex.ru',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'wehealth.herokuapp.com',
 'HTTP_TOTAL_ROUTE_TIME': '0',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)',
 'HTTP_VIA': '1.1 vegur',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '77.88.47.24, 10.33.252.175',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT': '80',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
 'HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID': 'a0a5b07f-b6be-40ec-b04a-81690188d0b4',
 'HTTP_X_REQUEST_START': '1558372953380',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/team/46/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': 'localhost',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'unix',
 'SERVER_PORT': '/tmp/nginx.socket',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'waitress',
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fc4b5d041e0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'waitress.buffers.ReadOnlyFileBasedBuffer'>,
 'wsgi.input': <newrelic.api.wsgi_application._WSGIInputWrapper object at 0x7fc4857e7310>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

**UPDATE**
Since it appears that my own app is causing the error. Here is the code in the async task that is associated with the error:

```
@shared_task
def createGoal2Group(group, goal):
    # "Create a Goal2Group link if user completes goal for first time"
    goal2group = Goal2Group.objects.get_or_create(group=group, goal=goal)
```

Comment: This kind of programming questions usually has more luck on Stack Overflow, especially if you're looking for advice on best practices.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @grawity. I agree that the solution ended up being a code-related fix, making it suitable for StackOverflow. However, given that it wasn't initially clear to me that my issue was internal, `I need to troubleshoot some software or hardware` seemed most appropriate, leading me to the `Super User` community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these things work in the opposite direction than you're imagining. The only time you see "Connection refused" is when *you* connect to another server.

(If your server doesn't accept HTTP connections, then the *clients* (i.e. Yandex bots) would be the ones getting "Connection refused" errors from the server – *not* your webapp. Plus, the webapp doesn't even handle connections in the first place – that's the job of the Heroku webservers.)

Take a closer look at your Python stacktrace: it goes from `wehealth.utils.get_group()` to the 'celery' async task package, then to the 'amqp' messaging client, which eventually reports an error from within amqp.transport. In other words, **your app fails to reach the AMQP server.**

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - that makes sense. My celery worker can successfully complete tasks in other aspects of the app in production. Why would it be causing an error in this specific instance? I will update the question to show the `createGoal2Group` task

Comment: Is the AMQP server managed by you or by Heroku? Maybe it begins refusing connections above a certain rate (e.g. if Yandex starts hammering the app at hundreds of requests/second)? Impossible for me to know.

Comment: Ahh that must be the case. Heroku is managing the AMQP server and the current configuration only allows 20 concurrent connections. Is there anything I can do within the app to prevent these error messages (or block such requests in the first place) or is it best to just troubleshoot through Heroku?

Comment: That's up to you... you can of course raise the limit, or you can [catch](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) the exception and decide whether to report it or not based on whatever parameters you decide. (E.g. suppress reporting when a crawler is making the request.) Or rate-limit the creation of new tasks (does every single page visit really need a task?) Or block Yandex and hope the problem goes away. Again, impossible for me to give project-specific advice in this case.